# Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

Tags: android, android-layout, notifications, remoteview

This question has been asked before but none of the answers helped me hence posting my case.

I am trying to build a custom notification using a layout file. But I get the following error:

> android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from
>   package com.eswaraj.app.eswaraj: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for:
>   StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.eswaraj.app.eswaraj user=UserHandle{0}
>   id=8888 tag=null score=0: Notification(pri=0
>   contentView=com.eswaraj.app.eswaraj/0x7f030052 vibrate=null sound=null
>   defaults=0x0 flags=0x0 kind=[null]))

My layout file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="left">

<com.makeramen.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/nImage"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_image"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
    app:riv_border_width="2dip"
    app:riv_border_color="#333333"
    app:riv_mutate_background="true"
    app:riv_oval="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nTitle"
    android:text="eSwaraj: Your voice is heard"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nImage"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nMessage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nTitle"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nImage"
    android:text="Your comaplaint viewed"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nTime"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nImage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nMessage"
    android:textSize="13dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="12:23PM"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I am sending notification as follows:

```
public void sendNotification(Context caller, Class<?> activityToLaunch, Bitmap icon,   GcmMessageDto gcmMessageDto, int id) {
        Intent toLaunch;
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(caller.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);
        if(activityToLaunch != null) {
            toLaunch = new Intent(caller, activityToLaunch);
       }
       else {
            toLaunch = new Intent();
        }
        PendingIntent intentBack = PendingIntent.getActivity(caller, 0, toLaunch, 0);

        NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager) caller.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(caller)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_notification_overlay)
                    .setContentIntent(intentBack);

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.nMessage, gcmMessageDto.getMessage());
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.nTime, new Date().toString());
        if(icon != null) {
            remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.nImage, icon);
        }
        mBuilder.setContent(remoteViews);

        notifier.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Shortly put, the

> com.makeramen.RoundedImageView

is messing with your job.

Not all views can be used in RemoteViews which are used for building custom notifications. According to [this official page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) only the following can be used for creating RemoteViews:

- FrameLayout
- LinearLayout
- RelativeLayout
- GridLayout
- AnalogClock
- Button
- Chronometer
- ImageButton
- ImageView
- ProgressBar
- TextView
- ViewFlipper
- ListView
- GridView
- StackView
- AdapterViewFlipper

So you must find a workaround for your modified ImageView class and use plain ImageView instead.

Comment: In my case, I was using `AppCompatImageView`. Switching to `ImageView` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, i was using a custom TextView, resorting to stock TextView solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue. As according to the accepted answer there are specific controls that can be used in the notification. I had a View in my layout for notification as below.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.04"/>
```

This was causing the crash. I removed it and it worked fine. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using a Constraint Layout and then I just followed the documentations https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout and changed to Linear Layout and it worked.

Comment: Please add some additional information from the link, as the link itself might break in the future